# iPhone app, help pages, multiple pages, quick to develop?

Tags: iphone

I need to provide some help for my app. I'm going to have some info buttons on some screens.

Initially I'd like them to be directed to the exact help page, but I'd like them then to be able to navigate to other pages in the help system.

What should I use, I'm looking for something quick to develop and quick to modify.

I'm thinking local html pages perhaps ?

Any examples / advice

Comment: Using local html pages for a help section sounds like a good idea to me. You could also check if the device is connected to the internet and load a different page if it is. That way you could have an always up-to-date FAQ for your app.

Comment: The only thing is apps I've seen which use web pages, always launch safari and leave the app. I want to remain in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is using a UIWebView to load HTML pages from your server. This way the user doesn't leave you app and the information can be updated or change as you may need.

Comment: If the app does not need internet access I, as a ipod touch user, would prefer if the help files are local.